# Getting only one match when I am expecting 3

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

Using regular expressions in C#, VS 2010.  Here's the code.

```
static string capturePattern = @"\|([!-|]{2})([!-|]{2})([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?\|";

Regex rgx = new Regex(capturePattern);

string TS="!3829.87N/12033.82Wv169/000|!('d%*|"

MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(TS);
```

matches.Count ends-up being 1 and matches[0] is "|!('d%*|".

I was expecting matches.Count to be 3, and parsed strings to be:

```
matches[0] = "!("
matches[1] = "'d"
matches[2] = "%*"
```

What did I do wrong?

Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex captures everything between the bars `|` into a single match. If you want the parts in parenthesis, those are in `match[0].Groups`.

`Group[0]` is the whole capture group. Groups 1, 2, and optionally, 3 and more are going to be the character pairs in parenthesis.

In your case, matches.Count will be 1, matches[0].Groups.Count will be 4, with :

```
matches[0].Group[1] == "!(" 
matches[0].Group[2] == "'d" 
matches[0].Group[3] == "%*"
```

Comment: Coincoin, I just coded this and the only issue is that matches[0].Groups.Count came back as 8, not 4. The extra four strings were empty and not needed. Shouldn't the '?' in the expression make those matches optional?

Answer (score -1):

[regexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) is your friend, test your expressions out there.

Comment: I've been using Expresso and the expression behaves as expected there. The difference occurs in the actual program I'm writing.

Comment: Being the half-way smart guy I am, I visited the web site and it is indeed my friend. It gives specific guidance in the .NET environment.

Back to coding.....

Comment: RegexBuddy is much nicer than this, though it isn't free.  Still, I'd recommend it: http://www.regexbuddy.com